# calculate all pairwise dot (inner) products between data points

Tags: linear-algebra, data-analysis, data-mining

Suppose we have $n$ data points in $\mathbb{R}^p$ and we would like to calculate all pairwise dot (inner) products between them.

How can I write a single matrix multiplication that does this?

(Some vectors and matrices will need to be defined carefully)

Comment: Just assemble your data into a matrix and take the product of the matrix with its transpose. The entries of this new matrix are the pairwise inner products you are after

Comment: What's an example of a single matrix multiplication that does this?

Comment: It seems to me that multiplying a matrix by its transpose is a *single* matrix multiplication. If that doesn't satisfy your definition then perhaps you should edit  the question to make you constraints more explicit